# NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

My app is throwing this error when accessing chromedriver:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:125)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:346)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:91)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
```

I've checked Guava version and it's using a decently new version of Guava:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>28.2-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

And selenium dependecies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The Chrome version on the server is:

```
root@localhost:~# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 85.0.4183.102
```

And the `chromedriver` version is this:

```
root@localhost:~# chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689})
```

What could be wrong or missing here that causes the exception to be thrown?